# PHP $_GET not reading my AJAX URL correctly

Tags: php, ajax, get

I'm not sure what the issue is, but my guess is that the $_GET variable won't read my ajax URL correctly, because of my deep linking plugin.

The final URL looks something like:
/dashboard.php#/projectSetup.php?mode=edit&getJobNumber=2012-30

HERE is my PHP:

```
$getJobNumber = $_GET['getJobNumber'];
$mode = $_GET["mode"];
```

When I echo $mode or $getJobNumber I am not getting a result. I believe the issue has to do with the format of the URL. Notice the 2 .php files and the # in the middle.

Please let me know if anyone knows of a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exactly right. Anything following the `#` in a url is considered the "document fragment", and is not sent to the server.

Do a "find" for "fragment" in [The URL RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) and you'll quickly see how using `#` in your urls for anything else is not compatible with the internet, in general.

Comment: ANy thoughts on how I can do this without using a POST?

Comment: @mitch: Yes, just send the page as a URL parameter: `/dashboard.php?page=projectSetup.php&mode=edit&getJobNumber=2012-30`.

Comment: @mitch Well, I *think so*, but I don't know all of your requirements. If `#/projectSetup.php` is there for the browser only, simply re-order the URL to place it after the get query string. If you need to pass that to the server, just convert it to another GET key, as drrcknlsn suggests.